# Returned int always zero + how to use object from Main method in sub-method

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple Java program for school that does the following:

**Gym Membership:** *"Write code that will input the customer’s age and number of months, and print the monthly rate and total amount to be charged. Prompt the user for the appropriate input, and display a meaningful output message. Make sure that the months are greater than 0 and the age is greater than 0."*

My problems are:

1. `custMonths` int is always getting returned as 0 and I don't know why.
2. I can't seem to find a way to loop back to the start of my `selectAge` method if the user gives bad input (negative number or zero).

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GymMembership {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //create test customer (customer0) via the constructor
    GymMembership customer0 = new GymMembership(70, 12);
    customer0.selectAge(customer0.custAge);
    customer0.printCustomer();
    customer0.getMonthlyRate(customer0.ageNamed);

    //prompt user for two integer inputs to create customer1
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter customer age, then number of months for contract: ");
    GymMembership customer1 = new GymMembership(scnr.nextInt(), scnr.nextInt());
    customer1.selectAge(customer1.custAge);
    customer1.printCustomer();
}

//the constructor
GymMembership(int custAge, int custMonths) {
    this.custAge = custAge;
    this.custMonths = custMonths;
}
//instance variables 
private int custAge;
private int custMonths;

int monthlyRate;    
int childRate = 15;
int adultRate = 25;
int seniorRate = 20;

String ageNamed;
public String selectAge(int custAge) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age = custAge;
    ageNamed = "badInput";
        do {
            if (age >= 1 && age <= 18) {
                ageNamed = "child";
            } 
            else if (age >= 19 && age <= 64) {
                ageNamed = "adult";
            }
            else if (age > 64 && age <= 120) {
                ageNamed = "senior";            
            }
            else {
                ageNamed = "badInput";
                System.out.println("Age must be a positive number between 1 and 120.");
                break;
            }   
        } while(ageNamed.equals("badInput"));       
    return ageNamed;
    }

public int getMonthlyRate(String ageNamed) {
    if (ageNamed.equalsIgnoreCase("child")) {
        monthlyRate = 15;
    } else if (ageNamed.equalsIgnoreCase("adult")) {
        monthlyRate = 25;
    } else {
        monthlyRate = 20;
    }
    return monthlyRate;
}

public void printCustomer() {
    if (ageNamed.equals("badInput") != true) {
        System.out.println("The customer is a/an " + ageNamed + " and is " + custAge + " years old.");
        System.out.println("The customer is signed up for a " + custMonths + " month contract.");
        System.out.println("The monthly rate is " + monthlyRate);   
    }
    else {
        selectAge(customer1.custAge); //this is broken since I cannot access customer1 object from this "printCustomer" method.
        }
    }
}
```

I realize I am very likely making some bad beginners mistakes here as well, but am not quite sure what they are.

Comment: Please see edits to answer and ask if any questions

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be over-complicating things. Some issues here including

- You've got user I/O within the GymMembership class where it doesn't belong. Get it out and into its own UI class or simply the main method.
- This includes not using Scanner within GymMembership as you're creating more than one Scanner based on System.in, a dangerous thing to do. Leave that in main.
- Get the input in main, and then use it to create your GymMembership object. Repeat as needed.
- I/O validation for age and months should also be in main. Again GymMembership should concern itself with just simply holding the state and behaviors of the object.
- Or I suppose you could give GymMembership a static boolean method that checks for valid age and months, and use that in the main method to tell if data entered is valid.
- The selectAge method is completely unnecessary as you're setting the age in the GymMembership's constructor. Again most of that code should be in the I/O section (main).
- This, `selectAge(customer1.custAge);` isn't valid **or** necessary. You're within the GymMembership class, the current object's age field is visible to you directly, use it.
- Your `getMonthlyRate(...)` method is dangerous in that it requires that a separate unnecessary field be calculated and passed in as a String, and this String is completely unnecessary, and likely this is causing you problems. The class already knows the information needed to calculate the rate via the age and months fields -- get rid of the String parameter and use the class's own fields.

e.g.,  the GymMembership class could be as simple as something like:

```
public class GymMemb2 {
    private int age;
    private int months;

    public GymMemb2(int age, int months) {
        this.age = age;
        this.months = months;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getMonths() {
        return months;
    }

    public double getMonthlyRate() {
        // calculations using age and months for monthly rate
        // return result
    }

    public String print() {
        String text = "age: " + age + ", months: " + months;
        // also add monthly rate info
        return text;
    }

}
```

Then in the main method, create the `new Scanner(System.in)` again, do this only once, and use it to get input. Within the main you'd use a while loop to keep looping until valid input has been entered, and then create your gym membership object(s). I think that the GymMembership class shouldn't have any println's within it but rather return Strings that may be printed by main if it desires.

Also at the end of main, close the Scanner by calling `.close()` on it. This should only be done with the program is completely done getting user input, since once closed it may not be reopened.

Comment: Thanks very much, @DontKnowMuchButGetterBetter ! I still can't seem to get int customerMonthlyRate to return anything but zero. Any idea why?

Comment: NM, another rookie mistake. Just forgot to call the method on the object in Main! :)